# What does "kviews" mean?

Tags: support, questions, views, terminology

As in the image shown, some questions have a certain number of `kviews` whereas others have N `views`.

Why? What is "kviews"?

[image]

Comment: Also, if you click on the question, you see the full number of views on the right.

Comment: Also also, if you hover your mouse cursor over the number, the `title` attribute (tooltip) displays the count in `views`. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

kviews = kiloviews == [1000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) views

The questions with nk views have nx1000 views.

Comment: also Mviews would be 1000000 views and mviews would be 0.001 views. Clic for an overview of [metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_prefixes).